# copy folder structure from internal memory to sd-card

Tags: shell, file-system

I use the amazon downloader to buy mp3s with my android device. My problem now is that I cannot change the download folder but want the files to be moved to my sdcard. I already found a cron tool to run scripts from time to time. All I need now is a shell script to move all folders (including subfolders and files) from

internalmemory\amazonmp3

to

sdcard\Music

to be honest my knowledge is just good enough to do a "mv" but not good enough to go through all subfolders. I also am not sure about the directory structure of android devices. (pathes to sdcard and so on)

Comment: @MatthewRead Because he's using cron to do it periodically on a preset timetable.

Comment: @onik Lol, I somehow totally missed that sentence, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `mv` on a directory containing files and subdirectories, it will move all of them. But in this case you may not want to move the `amazonmp3` directory itself, so the command would be `mv internalmemory/amazonmp3/* /sdcard/music/`, assuming the internalmemory directory is correct.

The actual names for the internal memory and sd-card depend on the device, for example on my old Galaxy S they were `/sdcard` and `/sdcard/external_sd/`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition. "mv" does NOT work on Android because the internal memory and sdcard have different file systems. You have to copy the files and then delete the old ones.

(oniks answer is still the best. This information is just for those who ended here using google)